# Do I need to persist a continuously updated RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, rdd

I'm working with a spark program which need to continuously update some RDD in a loop:

```
var totalRandomPath: RDD[String] = null
for (iter <- 0 until config.numWalks) {
  var randomPath: RDD[String] = examples.map { case (nodeId, clickNode) =>
    clickNode.path.mkString("\t")
  }

  for (walkCount <- 0 until config.walkLength) {
    randomPath = edge2attr.join(randomPath.mapPartitions { iter =>
      iter.map { pathBuffer =>
        val paths: Array[String] = pathBuffer.split("\t")

        (paths.slice(paths.size - 2, paths.size).mkString(""), pathBuffer)
      }
    }).mapPartitions { iter =>
      iter.map { case (edge, (attr, pathBuffer)) =>
        try {
          if (pathBuffer != null && pathBuffer.nonEmpty && attr.dstNeighbors != null && attr.dstNeighbors.nonEmpty) {
            val nextNodeIndex: PartitionID = GraphOps.drawAlias(attr.J, attr.q)
            val nextNodeId: VertexId = attr.dstNeighbors(nextNodeIndex)
            s"$pathBuffer\t$nextNodeId"
          } else {
            pathBuffer //add
          }
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage)
        }
      }.filter(_ != null)
    }
  }

  if (totalRandomPath != null) {
    totalRandomPath = totalRandomPath.union(randomPath)
  } else {
    totalRandomPath = randomPath
  }
}
```

In this program, RDD `totalRandomPath` and `randomPath` are constantly updated with a lot of transformation operations: `join` and `mapPartitions`. This program will end with action `collect`.

So need I persist those continuously updated RDDs(totalRandomPath, randomPath) to speed up my spark program?
And I notice that this program run fast in single node machine, but slow down when run in a three node cluster, why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to persist updated RDD and also unpersist older RDD

```
var totalRandomPath:RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List.empty[String]).cache()   
for (iter <- 0 until config.numWalks){

    // existing logic

    val tempRDD = totalRandomPath.union(randomPath).cache()
    tempRDD foreach { _ => } //this will trigger cache operation for tempRDD immediately  
    totalRandomPath.unpersist() //unpersist old RDD which is no longer needed
    totalRandomPath = tempRDD   // point totalRandomPath to updated RDD
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I just wonder that the spark can auto optimize transformations, why we bring in actions like foreach? Just to trigger cache operation? I know that spark also will write results to disk when shuffle happens.

Comment: why we bring in actions like foreach? Just to trigger cache operation?    =>  yes.     
If we dont do foreach, it wont persist RDD for each iteration and for every iteration entire calculation is triggered again and again.

Comment: spark also will write results to disk when shuffle happens => Not true for all the cases. spark only writes data to disk when data does not fit in memory during shuffle.

Comment: Thank you, but I have another question. Why we need persist those intermediate RDDs? If my memory is enough, spark will writes intermediate RDDs to memory, so why persist behaviour is required?

Comment: Correct. If you have enough memory then don't have to do persist. When application runs out of memory, it will remove RDD(totalRandomPath) which is not explicitly asked to persist and next time when it requires that RDD(totalRandomPath), it recalculates it.